# I got this error IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, numpy, math

I'm trying to make a python script to calculate some values of the zeta function, but when s<0, this is my script :

```
def funct(x,n):
    a = (x**(n-1))*(e**(-x))
    return a
def gamma(n):
    I = quad(func, 0, np.inf, args=n, full_output=0)
    ne = np.array(I)
    r = ne[(0,0)]
    return r

def zeta(s):
    z = (2**s)*(pi**s-1)*sin((pi*s)/2)*gamma(1-s)*zeta(1-s)
    return z
```

but when i try to print the gamma function i get an error :

```
File "/home/yassir/python/desktop/exp.py", line 38, in <module>
print(gamma(1))
File "/home/yassir/python/desktop/exp.py", line 30, in gamma
r = ne[(0,0)]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I don't know how to fix it, I want to mention the reason why I've written this line

```
 r = ne[(0,0)]
```

this is because i want just the first value of the array (ne).

Comment: Tne error means it's a 1-dimensional array, but you're using a 2-dimensional index.

Comment: Do you mean i should write r=ne[0]@Barmar

Comment: If `ne` is one dimensional, and you want the first index, then just do `r = ne[0]`

Comment: `quad` should be returning one value.  There's no need make a array from it, nor to select its 'first' value.  When you get errors like this, check the variables in the function. Often they aren't what you assume they will be.

Comment: no, i’ve tried to print it without the array and it didn’t work @hpaulj

Comment: what didn't work?  `return I`

Comment: Yes i got a 1 by 2 array @hpaulj